# save_post requiere at least one uploaded file to be published

Tags: save-post

Is there a way to check the Published status of a post, and if it doesnt has at least one image or file uploaded, then change status of published to draft?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but it should work:

```
function check_post_attachments($post_id, $post){
  if(empty(get_posts(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post_id)))){
     $post['post_status'] = 'draft';
     wp_update_post($post);
  }
}

add_action('save_post', 'check_post_attachments');
```